# Reneging Accepted Internship for Better Offer

Tags: software-industry, united-states, internship

**Context:**

A couple months ago I accepted an internship for this summer at a large, but unknown enterprise company.

The pay is fine, but the work is pretty irrelevant for the job market; Proprietary software, proprietary languages that only a few old companies use today and I'd be working on internal tools. I have no interest in working there as a full-time employee.

I got the job after being referred by a friend who is working there this summer.

**The Dilemma:**

I recently got an offer out of the blue from a previous internship boss who moved to a new company. The pay is 50% higher and the tech is modern and relevant. I'd also be working on production software and meaningful problems.

I am concerned that if I accept this new job, it could negatively affect my career as reneging would leave a black mark and they have already finished hiring.

Is it worth it to stay at the first job that is less relevant and interesting to prevent burning bridges?

Should I worry about burning bridges if I don't expect work with the 1st company's people anywhere else?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can renege.

The pay bump and the career prospects alone should be guiding you in this instance. The only blow-back could be that your friend might feel a little irritated, but you can probably just talk to them about it.

Internships are the beginning of your career, you want the best for you. Also, interns are generally viewed as flaky and given unimportant tasks, so nobody is going to be either surprised or distraught at your decision.